# Create STEPPED_AREA chart with dataLabel

Tags: google-sheets

After creating a STEPPED_AREA chart with a Google Script Macro, I am unable to enable the Data Label for any of the Series of the Chart.

I began by recording a macro to record the steps of creating a stepped area chart.  Everything copied over well except for dataLabels.  They don't display and I am unable to enable them with the checkbox in the Google Sheets program.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function change_axis() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B28').activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var chart = charts[0];
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.STEPPED_AREA)
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B7'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('backgroundColor', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', false)
  .setOption('legend.position', 'none')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.fontSize', 8)
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#ffff00')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.gridlines.count', 2)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.gridlines.color', '#ffff00')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.formatOptions.scaleFactor', 1)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.min', spreadsheet.getRange('B28').getValue())
  .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindowMode', 'explicit')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#ffff00')
  .setOption('series.0.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.0.areaOpacity', 0)
  .setOption('series.0.color', '#1155cc')
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabelPlacement', 'auto')
  .setOption('series.1.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.1.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.1.areaOpacity', 0)
  .setOption('series.1.color', '#00ff00')
  .setOption('series.1.dataLabelPlacement', 'auto')
  .setOption('series.2.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.2.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.2.areaOpacity', 0)
  .setOption('series.2.dataLabelPlacement', 'auto')
  .setOption('series.3.hasAnnotations', false)
  .setOption('series.3.dataLabel', 'none')
  .setOption('series.3.areaOpacity', 1)
  .setOption('series.3.color', '#00ffff')
  .setOption('series.3.dataLabelPlacement', 'auto')
  .setOption('series.4.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.4.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.4.areaOpacity', 1)
  .setOption('series.4.color', '#ff0000')
  .setOption('series.4.dataLabelPlacement', 'auto')
  .setOption('series.5.areaOpacity', 1)
  .setOption('series.5.color', '#ff0000')
  .setOption('width', 114)
  .setPosition(8, 1, 85, 0)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

I believe the .setOption('series.#.dataLabel', 'value') lines are my problem, but I cannot change it to anything that works.

[Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Gp8.png)

You can view the file at:  [Temperature Chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSXAEwC3qAqdcWvkskNgCaew6IQczwQruApiRNA5tFRj4M1EMG8zVOzL46gGUHUnUCrPuzRsr-KQy1F/pubhtml)

Comment: Welcome. It's quite difficult to comment about this question without seeing the underlying data that you are using. Please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Try this. **1)EDIT CODE:** `.setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)` and `.setPosition(3, 5, 13, 129)`. **2)DELETE CODE:** `.setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.min', spreadsheet.getRange('B28').getValue())` and `.setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindowMode', 'explicit')` and `.setOption('width', 114)` and `.setOption('vAxes.0.gridlines.count', 2)`. **3)RE-RUN** Delete the existing chart, and re-run the modified macro code.

Comment: The above isn't working.  The biggest issue is with the dataLabel and dataLabelPosition options.  I believe it is a bug because if I generate a Stepped Area Chart without the script, I have the option to add and manipulate data labels inside of Google Sheets.  When I use the script, I cannot edit the data label in Google Sheets anymore.  It won't even allow me to check the box for data labels on any of the series.

Comment: Hmm. That's not good. OK; **time for you to share your spreadsheet data**-we need to work with real data. Plus, _sorry to be pedantic_, but you _DID_ delete the existing chart, didn't you. The above changes were made to your code, **delete any existing chart**, and then re-run revised code. The resulting chart should look fine. Lastly, _are you wedded to that code_? The macro system creates a lot of useless stuff (just like _Word/Excel_); it would probably be better to create a chart with clean minimised code.

Comment: When the file is published, the data Labels also disappear (even if they were not generated with the macro).

Comment: Have you ever seen an example in the wild that looks like your successful outcome? If so, would you give a link to it. BTW, the link to your temperature chart is broken.